# How to format LOCALDATE in JPA query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

This is what you want to do and I have it in Postgres

```
SELECT distinct to_char(date, 'yyyy-MM') FROM public.Pruebas;
```

it returns 2023-02

I want to do this same thing in jpa this is my code

```
@Query("SELECT distinct to_char(e.id.date, 'yyyy-MM') FROM Pruebas e")
```

but to_char is giving me an error

I want to be able to have the same result that I have in Postgres but now from jpa 2023-02

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: the query returns distinct **months** so it's different to `distinct date`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?